# Sending data from an AsyncTask located in an Android Library to project Android AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-library

I have two projects: an Android main project and an Android library. In the Android Library i make use of Asynctasks and the data from onPostExecute i would like to be able to send to the android project that is importing this library. In this case the main project is a widget app, but this should not be relevant i think.
I was thinking of using on onActivityResult in my main project, but it seems as a bad idea.

This is how i call my library from the main project:

```
 Intent libraryIntent = new Intent(context, ComplicatedRequest.class);
 libraryIntent.addFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(libraryIntent);
```

In my library project, in the onPostExecute method, i don't know how to send the data from there back to my app. I am almost sure it's a trivial question, but i rather ask then implement a rather bad practice solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use startActivityForResult (cf. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (example from official doc) :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

    protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
            // When the user center presses, let them pick a contact.
            startActivityForResult(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, new Uri("content://contacts")), PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it to the user.
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve values via data.getStringExtra(String name) (or other types if needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Intent and IntentFilter(Manifest)
<i>
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
 intent.put("key", value);
 context.startActivity(intent);
</i>

In Activity
<i>
 String s = intent.getExtra().getString("key");
 </i>
```